# .htaccess settings for multiple websites with one document root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web, webserver

My Hoster allows multiple Website but just with one DocumentRoot for all domains.

**What I want are site with different content:**

```
https://www.site1.com
https://www.site2.com
```

**What I have:**

```
Directory Structure
/html/ <- Document root
/html/site1.com/ <- Symlink to /pages/site1.com/web
/html/site2.com/ <- Symlink to /pages/site2.com/web
```

**How it should work:**

```
Browser: https://www.site1.com/folder/ 
<- this will internally gets internally redirected to /pages/site1.com/web/folder/
```

**The current .htaccess solution:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/site1.com/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site1.com/$1 [L,NC]
```

It IS working, if I visit https://www.site1.com/folder/.

**But the problem, what I dont want:**

1.) If I visit site1.com/folder (without last slash), the webserver automatically redirects to https://www.site1.com/site1.com/folder/ instead of https://www.site1.com/folder/. 
I think this is due to the auto trailing slash feature of directories from Apache (Shared Web Hoster with limited ssh account). 
One possible solution would be to redirect 301 all web browser https://*site*/*sitefolder*.com/ request uri's to the non /site1.com/ request uri's.
But every htaccess rule i tested *failed*.

2.) I dont want to make the http://www.site1.com/site1.com & https://www.site1.com/site2.com urls accessable due to duplicated content.

**How can I fix this problems and have one document root with multiple domains as subdirectories without duplicated content / redirects to the subfolders INSIDE the url?**

Comment: Can you change the examples with the full URL including http. I'm confused if `site1.com/site1.com/folder/` should mean `http://site1.com/site1.com/folder/` or `http://site1.com/site1.com/site1.com/folder/`
and if you mean the folder form the Server point of view add `/html/`  e.g.: `/html/site1.com/site1.com/folder/`

Answer (score 0):

This could not be done in 3 lines, so here is what I would do:

```
RewriteEngine On

# First we check if we have a direct access to our folder and prevent it with a 404 Error
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?site1\.com(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?site2\.com(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]

# Optional you can redirect all non-www to www, http or https stay the same
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Now we rewriting all request based on the requesting host works with www and non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

The answer assume that the folder is called the same as the host but without leading `www.`, as you have it in your question. So for `http://www.example.com` the folder have to be `example.com`.